# What is populating a force "field"?

Tags: field-theory

What "matter" is populating a force "field"? It can't be actually empty?

Comment: You need to look up the definition of a "field" as used in physics.

Comment: In high energy physics "matter" is being described with a special set of fields which, in certain asymptotic cases, can also give rise to what we used to call a force field (like the electrostatic or magnetic field), so they are basically two sides of the same coin. Matter doesn't cause the force fields, but both matter and force fields are caused by something third, which is called a "quantum field".

Comment: Are you talking about 'force field' of _molecular mechanics_?

Comment: To all : sorry for not being clear about exactly what I'd like to have an answer about! What I'm curious to know about is, for example, when we scatter iron fillings around a bar magnate, the fillings get organised in a manner depicting the Lines of Force  --  but what really does physically move/arrange the fillings, albeit invisibly? We may define it as Magnetic Field, but is it essentially some Energy [which, I presume, is a transformed Matter in a way]?